# Listing files into listbox by date modified

Tags: c#, file, date, listbox

I am trying to get the text files from a certain directory and list them by date modified into a listBox.
Here is my current code, but I have no idea how do order them by date modified.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@".\notes\");
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.txt"))
    listBox1.Items.Add(fi.Name.Substring(0, fi.Name.Length - 4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built-in [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) method:

```
foreach(FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.txt").OrderBy (d => d.LastWriteTime))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(fi.Name.Substring(0, fi.Name.Length - 4));
}
```

If you want them in descending order, there is [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).